# ASP.net code behind and back from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple page per below:

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<html>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="Default.aspx">

Enter Number: <input type="text" name="cNum" value="7707744436276244" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

and code behind Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string ServerSideVariable;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string n = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form['cNum']); ERROR Here<--- too many character in character literall....

        string pval = "Passed value";
        ServerSideVariable = pval;

    }
}
```

why the error occuring?

Also i'm planning to implement in code behind to make connectivity with DB and return the response back to ASP.net, any one know how is this done?

Comment: Any one know how can you pass value back from C# (code behind) to ASP.net (or up wards) is it just simply refering the var in asp.net? or does the XML file at the top needs to pull it?

Comment: ADO.net doesnt do oracle PL/SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# the `'` is reserved for character literal.
The `"` is reserved for string literal.

```
char char1 = 'Z';        // Character literal
string string1 = "ZZZ";  // String literal
```

C# References:

- [Character literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [[] Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string ServerSideVariable;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string n = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["cNum"]); //ERROR Here<--- too many character in character literall....

        string pval = "Passed value";
        ServerSideVariable = pval;

    }
}
```

As for you second question, please read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html.

Comment: +1: explains WHY you must use double quote and not single quote.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have more than one character inside the `' '` marks. Your code should read:

```
string n = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["cNum"]); // Double quotes here
```

As for your second question, that's a very broad question covering a lot of db topics/possibilities. You should narrow down your question to ask something specific with respect to this.

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes. Single quotes are for one character.

```
Request.Form["cNum"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
string n = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form['cNum']);
```

To

```
string n = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["cNum"]);
```

You need double quotes (`" "`) to denote a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error occurs because Request.From has many parameters.

To get the Post parameters the better approach is :

```
NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = Request.Form;

string cnum = nameValueCollection["cNum"];
```

Although i have not tested, but i think this will do good.